# Why does Google Sheets' FILTER formulae change output when inside IFS formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When using a FILTER formula Google Sheets gives output as expected
`=filter(A1:C15,A1:A15="ABC")`

But when I wrap that in an IFS formula it only gives the first value
`=ifs(A1="ABC", filter(A1:C15,A1:A15="ABC"),A1="123", filter(A1:C15,A1:A15="123"))`

Example spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wZsTXGdnzCqwwyBxWpne2n-B577_bQvXPhgcTRQGWqk/edit#gid=411641402

What have I done wrong?

Thanks
MTwem

Comment: Your sheet is locked. Please set the link's permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." Or add me as an editor (I send a message via the locked form requesting edit permission).

Comment: Oops sorry my bad

Comment: Unlike `IF()`, the `IFS()` function will fail in returning a range. Seems like implicit intersection behaviour is in place or rather [*"Array expected output = Array expected input"*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124685/247436) . Try: `=IF(OR(A1="ABC",A1=123),FILTER(A1:C15,A1:A15=A1))`

Comment: Nice one JvdV! Chuck it in the answers section and I'll accept it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from JvdV in the comments section:

Unlike `IF()`, the `IFS()` function will fail in returning a range. Seems like implicit intersection behaviour is in place or rather "Array expected output = Array expected input" . Try: `=IF(OR(A1="ABC",A1=123),FILTER(A1:C15,A1:A15=A1))` – JvdV

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, all you need is this:

`=FILTER(A1:C15,A1:A15=A1)`